# How do you pronounce serpentine?

Tags: pronunciation

I have hear serpentine pronounced sir-pen-tine and sir-pen-teen. Which is correct or more common?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. A good dictionary will give you commonly accepted pronunciations, and a number of online dictionaries include audio clips in "standard" British and American accents. We have a compilation of [good reference works on English](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573), and I also encourage you to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer for UK.

Your first is universal (for adjective, noun and Name of place) in UK. Listen here:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/serpentine

The second is given by the American Merriam-Webster.  Listen here:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serpentine